# How to stop card children from overflowing at the bottom?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a card with a title, *task description*, *icons with labels* and a *button*. When the description is very long, the card doesn't want to extend it's height any more to fit the children so the *icons with labels* and the *start button* start to overflow at the bottom of the card (see [screenshot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iCdl.png)).

Even though, for the shorter descriptions it has no problem fitting all the children inside the card.

Here is what I did to create the *task description*:

```
  // task description i.e. 'Delivieries in Bay 6 need...'
    final taskdescription = Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Text(
            task.description,
            overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
            style: descriptionfont,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

and to make the icons with labels and the start button:

```
// time, status, button
    final taskstatus = Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          flex: 2,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[

              // time with icon i.e. '09:00 am'
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Icon(
                    Icons.timer,
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(76, 76, 76, 1),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text(
                      task.completeBy,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
                      style: statusfont,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),

              // status with icon i.e. 'Not Started'
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Icon(
                    Icons.remove_circle_outline,
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(76, 76, 76, 1),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Not Started',
                      overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
                      style: statusfont,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),

        // button i.e. 'Start'
        Column(
          children: [
            OutlinedButton.icon(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.start,
                size: 20,
              ),
              style: statusbuttonstyle,
              label: Text(
                'Start',
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                style: buttonfont,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
```

Then I put each of these into a single card:

```
// task card
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        boxShadow: const [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.3),
            blurRadius: 10,
            spreadRadius: -15.0,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      child: Card(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
        ),
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              tasktitle,
              SizedBox(height: 15),
              taskdescription, // task description
              SizedBox(height: 15),
              taskstatus, // time, status, button
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Not sure if this is relevant but to display the list of cards I did this:

```
body: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
                physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: taskList.length,
                prototypeItem: TaskCard(taskList[0]),
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return TaskCard(taskList[index]);
                }),
          ),
        ],
```

Help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `prototypeItem` property in `ListBuilder` forces the child elements to have the same size as this widget in the scrolling direction. Thus, all widgets in `ListBuilder` have the same height as the first widget, which is much smaller than the others and causes overflow. So the issue can be solved by setting null to the `prototypeItem`.

```
  ListView.builder(
    itemCount: list.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) => CustomContainer(text: list[index]),
  ),
```